# .gitignore isn't ignoring files in certain folder

Tags: c#, git, asp.net-core, gitignore

I have a .gitignore file.

One of my declarations is

**/bin/Debug/
**/obj/Debug/

But it's still picking up these files

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell git to remove the from the repository first.

```
git rm --cached bin/Debug
git rm --cached obj/Debug
```

Then commit changes.

Comment: That's actually not working. It was initially then after rebooting my machine, it stopped.