# Ignoring "appsettings.json" from being uploaded to github

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, asp.net-core

I would like visual studio to ignore "appsettings.json" from being uploaded to github repository.

I have tried putting the file name in .gitignore but visual studio 2017 still record it as a change and push it to the repository

```
## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.

# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.userosscache
*.sln.docstates

appsettings.json

# User-specific files (MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio)
*.userprefs
```

I expect the "appsettings.json" to be ignored when pushing the changes to the repository.

Comment: PM> git rm --cached appsettings.json
git : fatal: pathspec 'appsettings.json' did not match any files
At line:1 char:1
+ git rm --cached appsettings.json
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (fatal: pathspec...match any files:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Answer (score 0):

Same issue as here: [.gitignore isn't ignoring files in certain folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55342574/gitignore-isnt-ignoring-files-in-certain-folder)

```
git rm --cached appsettings.json
```

Comment: It can be a little more complicated than just removing from the next revision.... For example.... what will happen if you do this, commit, checkout the previous revision and then go back to the tip of the branch? Goodbye appsettings.json. Not really good bye... you can always get it back from git, of course.. but you get the idea, right? if you want the file to be _gone_ from the history of the branch, you would need to rewrite history.

Comment: True... if you want it permanently gone... git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch path_to_file" HEAD